# How to search in NCBI database and Show search results in my own site in my own language?

Tags: search, ncbi

NCBI is a comprehensive databank in genetics and biology but lots of us like to work with databases in our lauguage not others. I am designing a site which have to search NCBI data and make search in this data but dont show data results in NCBI and return data results to my site which has a Farsi interface. How can I do this? I mean, how can I use NCBI database search engine and show search results, in my site?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ncbi eutilities. You can read about it [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25501/)